# PHP setting input values with isset

Tags: php

I was wondering if there is a shorter way of writing the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?if(isset($_POST['username'])){ echo $_POST['username']; }?>" />
```

I hate having to do this will all my forms as the isset() check really messes up my HTML and scares away the frontenders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can make a helper:

```
function req($key, $default = '')
{
  return isset($_REQUEST[$key]) ? $_REQUEST[$key] : $default;
}

<input name="user" value="<?php echo htmlentities(req('user')) ?>" />
```

[@marvin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039024/php-setting-input-values-with-isset/2039039#2039039) suggestion is nice for your script as well

regarding the front-end folks, i would say give them some basic php to use, like in this php for designers tutorial:  http://www.digital-web.com/articles/php_for_designers/

learning the basic scrips i think is better than using an external templating system

Comment: You could also put the htmlentities into the req function, perhaps as an option, to simplify things further.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign the values in php part and then just echo in html

```
$username = isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:'';

<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>" />
```